# Location Updates Being Throttled on Android 5.1 Lollipop

Tags: android, gps, location, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am maintaining an Android application that obtains the current device location as many times per minute as possible using the CommonsWare LocationPoller library. I query for location data every 5 seconds, and on pre-5.1 devices it works perfectly, getting a new location at maximum every 7 seconds but after updating the same device Lollipop the device can only seem to obtain the location every 30 seconds (despite using a WakeLock). Is this a new power saving feature, and if so, can I disable it?

Comment: This library here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll

Comment: Yeah, that's been discontinued for two years and hasn't been updated for a year or two prior to that. *I* wouldn't use it, and it's my own library. That being said, Android 5.1 has some power-related undocumented stuff (e.g., cannot schedule a repeating alarm with a lower period than one minute), so it's not out of the question that there are changes related to locations tied to power as well.

Comment: Thank you for the super fast and informative replies, you are an incredible asset to SO. "Cannot schedule a repeating alarm with a lower period than one minute" seems like it could be the culprit.

Comment: I'm not using `AlarmManager` directly in there, unless it is hidden behind a thick layer of dust. :: sneezes :: I don't know much about how the GPS stuff works under the covers, so it's possible that `LocationManager` itself uses `AlarmManager`. Otherwise, it's probably not tied to `AlarmManager` directly, but might be just another bit of throttling they added. And thanks for the kind words!